# Difference between xmlhttp (js) and $http (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, ajax, xmlhttprequest

In normal JavaScript we use `xmlhttp` for Ajax. Angular is providing ajax service using `$http`. Is there anything extra things in `$http` compare to `xmlhttp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http` in AngularJS cannot be configured to be synchronous while `xmlhttp` can do either synchronous or asynchronous. In AngularJS world, we use `$http` because it is the "Angular way" of doing requests.